# Boosting results based on document indexed time showing in reverse order

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to boost the relevancy of search results based on the last indexed time of the doc. So, if there are multi matches for a search query, I am boosting the results based on the last indexed timestamp.

This is the code I have written for boosting the result.

```
new FunctionDecayRule<Int64, String>()
{
    Description = "Boost search results based on the last indexed timestamp.",
    Target = Target.RootNode,
    Origin = int.MaxValue,
    Scale = "1s",
    Function = DecayFunction.Linear,
    Field = CodeSearchFieldDesc.IndexedTimeStamp.ElasticsearchFieldName()
}
```

Whenever I am making any changes in the doc, that doc is coming **last** in the search results whereas it should be on the top since it is the most recent indexed doc.

Any idea or suggestion what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was with the `Origin` value. It was too big and all the scores of the docs were decayed to zero due to the too much distance from the `Origin`. I Changed it to the current time and now it's working as expected.